# Audio Response with Dialogflow and C#

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

On the Dialogflow speech setting I have enabled 'Automatic text to Speech'.

It says the output audio will be included in DetectIntentResponse and StreamingDetectIntentResponse but I'm not entirely sure how to go about this.

My scripts currently return the textual response using content.queryResults,fulfilmentText

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Detect intent with audio output](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/detect-intent-tts) in the official documentation for an example of a similar behavior.

You need to look for the "outputAudio" field in the response which contains a large base64 audio string. There is no example in C#, however you should be able to access it in a similar fashion as you access fulfillmentText. For example for Node.js

```
const audioFile = response.outputAudio
const text = response.queryResult.fulfillmentText
```

and for Python

```
text = response.query_result.fulfillment_text
audio = response.output_audio
```

So I assume for C# will be something like

```
content.outputAudio
```

Which, remember, will give you a large base64 audio string.